# Pass current text as parameter to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this function :

```
function getlst() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/Configuration/GetListParameter",
            success: function (data) {
                EmptyGridStep1();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   
                    $('#tableBody').append('<tr><td><label id="id" name="id" >' + data[i].id + ' </td>'
                     + '<td>' + data[i].key + '</td>' 
                     + '<td><input type="text"   onchange="keydown();"  value="' + data[i].value + '" /></td></tr>');
                }
                initGrid();
            }
        });
    }
```

**The Keydown function**

```
function keydown(value ) 
{
    alert(value);
}
```

I'd like to change :

```
<td><input type="text" onchange="keydown();" value="' + data[i].value + '" /></td>
```

To pass the current text as a paramater to `keydown` function.

How can I modify my code to accomplish this task?

Comment: You cannot. What you could do is call a different function which retrieves the value from the html element and then calls keydown with this as parameter.

Comment: _To pass the current text as a paramater to keydown function_, current text of what ? you mean input value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do so. All you have to do is pass the `input` itself as a parameter to your keydown function

```
<td><input type="text"   onchange="keydown(this);"  value="' + data[i].value + '" /></td>
```

and just read its value here

```
 function keydown(input) 
    {
        alert(input.value);
    }
```

Not the most elegant way to do it, I suggest instead of using `onchange`, you use `jquery`'s `change` event , so you have one single listener for your change event

```
 $('#tableBody').on("change", "input", function() {
  console.log( this.value );
});
```

You should read [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/).